# System.data.sqlite dll missing when exporting to android

Tags: c#, android, godot, system.data.sqlite

`System.DllNotFoundException: SQLite.Interop.dll assembly:<unknown assembly>`

I am using `Godot 3.5.2` with `C#` and `System.data.sqlite` for database connections. I am using Godot to export the project to my android device for debugging. Upon launching the app, the app crashes upon the first usage of `System.data.sqlite` in the project.

`using (IDbConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("res://datastore/database.db"))`

I have seen **Using Native Library Pre-Loading** https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki | I have all of the necessary dlls in the correct locations as detailed on the webpage.

I found the dlls, they are both found in an x64 and an x86 directory in bin, although, I'm not really understanding why it is in a temp folder?

Example path:

C:\dev\godot\godot_projects\mobile_rpg.mono\temp\bin\ExportDebug\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll

There is also:

C:\dev\godot\godot_projects\mobile_rpg.mono\temp\bin\Debug\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll

I have tried putting the both x86 and x64 folders in different places in the project, to no success.

I also found this:

C:\dev\godot\godot_projects\mobile_rpg.mono\temp\bin\ExportDebug\runtimes\win-x64\native\e_sqlite3.dll